# Armazenar código HTML na base de dados?

Tags: php

Estou a desenvolver um *script* que recupere códigos **HTML** a partir de um formulário, e em seguida armazenar na base de dados. No entanto gostaria de armazenar o código na base tal como ele foi inserido no formulário, com as tags, estilo, classes, etc...

**OBJECTIVO** :

- Por exemplo, se eu armazenar o código

  `<div style='color:red;'>Meu texto</div>`

Ao ler essa informação (com PHP por exemplo :  **`echo $informacoes_da_base`**) gostaria de obter como resultado "Meu texto" em vermelho.

**PROBLEMA** :

- As tags estão sendo interpretadas assim que chegam na base. Ex. : `&lqt;code &lql;`
- Ao ler as informações na base ex.: **`echo $informacoes_da_base`** obtenho no ecrã caracteres não desejáveis.

Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre **`mysql_escape_string`** e **`html_entity_decode`** mas não consigo obter os resultados pretendidos.

**`echo html_entity_decode($infos_da_base);`**

**`echo mysql_escape_string($infos_da_base);`**

**CÓDIGO** :

```
if(isset($_POST['enregistrer'])){

  Configuration::updateValue('DESCRIPTION_TIME_DELIVERY', $_POST['description']);

}
```

```html
<form>
   <textarea style="width: 200px;">
       <code style='color: red;'>codigo html aqui</code>
   </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Como tu estás fazendo? Posta o código.

Comment: Estás a passar os dados por alguma função antes de inserires na base de dados certo? Qual é? Consegues saber?

Comment: Isso não deve ser verdade: "As tags estao sendo interpretadas assim que chegam na base. Ex. : &lqt;code &lql;" - se está sendo convertido, é antes da base.

Comment: Ponha o trecho de código que captura o formulário, e que salva no DB, que provavelmente a comunidade vai achar o problema lá. Só com o código que você postou, o problema não pode ser reproduzido.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `htmlentities()` para codificar esse caracteres e então as tags ficarão assim: `&lt;/img&gt;` essa codificação é: `<img/>`, feito isso é só salvar no BD.
   No momento de retorna esses dados se você for jogá-los diretamente no DOM então não precisa passar função para decodifica porque o navegador já faz isso, agora se você for colocá-lo dentro de alguma `input` ou `textarea` passe antes na função `html_entity_decode()` para retorna os caracteres originais.

Resumo:

```
<?php
$a = htmlentities('<img/>'); //Retorno "&lt;/img&gt;"
$b = html_entity_decode($a); //Retorno "<img/>"
```

Comment: Isso é gambiarra no meu ver, não precisa codificar pra salvar no DB. O decode pode ser usado para exibir como código, mas não precisa (e nem deve) codificar nada no DB à toa. O autor tem um problema na hora de salvar, e esta parte não foi postada na pergunta.

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas tentei deixar claro como funciona as funções. 
Como ele disse ter tentado usar `mysql_escape_string` e `html_entity_decode`creio que ele esteja errando na lógica para retorna os valores.

Comment: Sim, dentro do possível você postou o que podia, e o autor aceitou a resposta. Só avisei para que qualquer pessoa que venha a ler entenda que provavelmente a solução real para o problema vem antes disso. A falta de detalhes da pergunta impede a análise completa.